# Recommendation for usb drive pool

Tags: linux, lvm, usb-drive, zfs, storage

I have a server with a large amount of storage. I also have a bunch of large USB drives that I would like to use as a backup volume.

My question is, on Linux, is there any reliable way to do a storage pool with multiple usb drives? If possible, being able to add more on the way.

The backup server would be running on Linux, so should I use LVM? ZFS? Anything else?

Comment: what is the current system running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use ZFS, due to the fact, I trust in ZFS to guarantee the data integrity due to it checksums. But it depends on the size of your storage. What is huge for you? 5 TB, 50 TB or several hundred TB? In that case it might be better to use a tape drive than dealing with USB devices. I backup my local server storage to a couple of external USB3 hard drives via ZFS send and receive feature. I am talking about 12 TB data so far. But in case you need more than 5-10 disks I would switch to tape backup.

Comment: i am also talking about around 12-14TB. I plan to get my hands on an LTO drive in the near future...

Comment: Below 15 TB external drives might be sufficient. eSATA or USB3. In case of mirrored configuration and 6 TB drives, you would need 6 hdds... That seems okay to me and is probably cheaper than an LTO drive

Answer (score 0):

I'd also agree with Frank in preferring ZFS for not only data integrity, but other features the filesystem offers.

Your question also hints that you're considering building a backup server running Linux or something else?  If so, there are various open source offerings which meet your needs. Here are two that I can recall:

- Nexenta (uses ZFS):  https://community.nexenta.com/s/
- freenas

Comment: I was thinking about the bacula software which would give me flexibility of switching to a tape library.